# port on Layer 2 switches Mac Address usage

Tags: cisco-commands

**Why each and every single port on Layer 2 switches need to have it's own MAC address?
This question has been asked and answered with each has it's own MAC and one of the purposes was STP protocol use.

My question is that are these mac addresses used for etherchannel load balancing whenever the portchannel configured to load balance based on src-dst mac?is the source mac in cisco command indicating to the port mac address?

Thanks, 
Ethem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the source mac address that used in the algorithm is the source mac address in the Ethernet frame to be transmitted (I.E. the mac address of the host that sent the frame), it has nothing to do with the switch port mac address.

(and many switches don't have a per-port mac address).

Comment: thanks for the clear answer,,in this case what is the best way to do load balancing on etherchannel ports creatd from 4 phsical links between connection like: esx --> sw1 -->sw2 --> bckp server to back up data from virtual servers on ESX to bckp server and in between 2 switches (sw1 & sw2),,thanks

Comment: In an etherchannel (or LACP) link, a single flow will always use a single link. Different flows may use different links. The algorithm is used to determine which link will be used by a flow, based on criteria like mac addresses for example (we can also use source and destination IP addresses). There's some chance that 2 flows will use the same link while other links are still unused. The more flows, the better the balancing.